# How to create an object inside the CreateView in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views, django-2.0

I want to create and save an object in my View using CreateView.

[> example in django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview), uses a form to create new object while I have the fields value (I know the user and the book he selected) and want to create it inside the view, something like this.

```
from django.views import generic

class BookReserveView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Reservation
    person = current_login_user # the user who logged in
    book = selected_book      # selected book (I have the pk)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('book:reserve_book') # when the object saved go to this url
```

and this is my Reservation model.

```
class Reservation(models.Model):

    person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Copy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    date_reserved = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I tried this code and it worked for me. but I like to use generic views (CBV)

```
from book.models import Copy,Reservation

def BookReserveView(request,pk):
    book = Copy.objects.get(pk=pk)
    reserve_obj = Reservation(book=book, person=request.user)
    reserve_obj.save()
    return HttpResponse(str(reserve_obj))
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you try the CBV you have there?

Comment: @leelum1 you can't use pk for getting book in the way I use.so it say 'name 'pk' is not defined
'

Answer (score 0):

You should use form_valid method inside you CBV 
look at documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#form_valid, like     `form.instance.user = self.request.user` for giving your values